# Opening a WIKI URL with a comma using `open-uri`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, open-uri

I am running in to `OpenURI::HTTPError: 403 Forbidden` error
when I try to `open` a URL with a comma (OR other special characters like `.`).
I am able to open the same url in a browser.

```
require 'open-uri'
url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thor_Industries,_Inc."
f = open(url)
# throws OpenURI::HTTPError: 403 Forbidden error
```

How do I escape such URL?

I have tried to escape the url with `CGI::escape` and I get the same error.

```
f = open(CGI::escape(url))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Typically, one would simply require the module `cgi`, then use `CGI::escape(str)`.

```
require 'cgi'
require 'open-uri'
escaped_page = CGI::escape("Thor_Industries,_Inc.")
url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/#{escaped_page}"
f = open(url)
```

However, this doesn't seem to work for your particular instance, and still returns a 403. I'll leave this here for reference, regardless.

---

**Edit:** Wikipedia is refusing your requests because it suspects that you are a bot. It would seem that certain pages that are clearly content are granted to you, but those that don't match its "safe" pattern (e.g. those that contain dots or commas) are subject to its screening. If you actually output the content (I did this with `Net::HTTP`), you get the following:

> Scripts should use an informative User-Agent string with contact information, or they may be IP-blocked without notice.

Providing a user-agent string, however, solves the issue:

```
open("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thor_Industries,_Inc.",
  "User-Agent" => "Ruby/#{RUBY_VERSION}")
```

Comment: I had tried `CGI::escape` with similar results. I forgot to add it in my question.

Comment: You might want to see what output you're getting. I remember a few weeks ago Wikipedia started giving me 403 errors when making requests from Ruby because I wasn't supplying any user-agent string, and the output said so.

Comment: @KandadaBoggu: Yep, that was it. Edits made.

Comment: Brilliant! It works. Unrelated Question: Do you throttle your requests to wiki to avoid rate limits?

Comment: It was just a side-project I was working on for a few hours; I never actually got to the point where I hit rate limits. If they actually do have that sort of system, though, then you may need to make some sort of call like that.